# Why are the Lucas numbers and Fibonacci numbers linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

[The answer for this question](https://brilliant.org/problems/non-obvious-basis/?ref_id=1232023) states (without giving too much else away):

> Since $F$ and $L$ are linearly independent ...

Using the definition of [linear dependence for infinite dimensions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Linear_independence), I presume that if I am able to find a finite subset of $L$ and $F$ such that the elements are not all zero and the resulting sum is $0$ the two sets are not linearly independent. I chose $2_{(L)} + (-1)2_{(F)} = 0$.

What is wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 4):

A sequence with characteristic polynomial $x^2-x-1$, i.e. a sequence $\{A_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ fulfilling $A_{n+2}=A_{n+1}+A_n$, is fixed by the initial values $A_0$ and $A_1$. We may notice that
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}F_0 & L_0 \\ F_1 & L_1 \end{pmatrix}\neq 0 \tag{1}$$
and by Gaussian elimination
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}F_n & L_n \\ F_{n+1} & L_{n+1} \end{pmatrix}=\pm \det\begin{pmatrix}F_0 & L_0 \\ F_1 & L_1 \end{pmatrix} \tag{2}$$
hence the Fibonacci and Lucas sequences are linearly independent.
We just used the analogue of the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) for DE.